# How Thread.sleep() works internally

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Let's say I have a thread T and it is holding one resource R. If I call Thread.sleep() on the current thread i.e T, will it release the resource R (to let other threads use it) before going to sleep or not?
Or it will hold that resource and again when it will awake it will use the resource R and after finishing the work will it release it?

Comment: can you be more specific about your example of resource

Comment: In general, no. No resources are released upon going to sleep.

Comment: @JigarJoshi, Ordinarily I would ask the same question, but since I know that sleep() doesn't close or release _anything_, it doesn't really matter in this case.  All a programmer needs to know about sleep(n) is that it will block the caller until an interrupt occurs, or n milliseconds have elapsed (whichever comes sooner).  It doesn't do anything else besides that.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, Thread.sleep() is Blocking library method. Threads may block, or pause, for several reasons: waiting for I/O completion, waiting to acquire a lock, waiting to wake up from Thread.sleep, or waiting for the result of a computation in another thread. When a thread blocks, it is usually suspended and placed in one of the blocked thread states.

So, when you call the sleep() method, Thread leaves the CPU and stops its 
     execution for a period of time. During this time, it's not consuming CPU time, 
     so the CPU can be executing other tasks.When Thread is sleeping and is 
     interrupted, the method throws an InterruptedException exception immediately 
     and doesn't wait until the sleeping time finishes.

The Java concurrency API has another method that makes a Thread object leave the CPU. It's the yield() method, which indicates to the JVM that the Thread object can leave the CPU for other tasks. The JVM does not guarantee that it will comply with this request. Normally, it's only used for debug purposes.

One of the confusion with sleep() is that *how it is different from wait() method of object class*.

The major difference between wait and sleep is that wait() method release the  acquired monitor when thread is waiting while Thread.sleep() method keeps the  lock or monitor even if thread is waiting.

Answer (score 8):

From [this Javamex article](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml):

> The [Thread.sleep()](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml) method effectively "pauses" the current thread for a given period of time. We used it in our very first [threading example](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/index.shtml) to make threads display a message periodically, sleeping between messages. From the outset, it's important to be aware of the following:
>
> - it is always the **current** thread that is put to sleep;
> - the **thread might not sleep** for the required time (or even at all);
> - the sleep duration will be subject to some system-specific
>     **granularity**, typically 1ms;
> - while sleeping, the thread **still owns synchronization locks** it has
>     acquired;
> - the sleep can be interrupted (sometimes useful for implementing a
>     cancellation function); calling sleep() with certain values can have
>     some subtle, global effects on the OS (see below), and vice versa,
>     other threads and processes running on the system can have subtle
>     effects on the observed sleep duration.

Answer (score 3):

The thread which is going to sleep will hold the lock`(not release resource)` while it sleeps. A sleeping thread will not even be scheduled for the time it sleeps (or until it is interrrupted and then it wakes up)

Answer (score 1):

If your resource R is java monitor, then there are only two ways to release it:

- exit `synchronized` block
- call `wait` on owned monitor

Answer (score 1):

**Javadoc** says - `sleep()`:  *Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers*

The Thread.sleep() method essentially interacts with the thread scheduler to put the current thread into a wait state for the required interval. The thread however does not lose ownership of any monitors.

In order to allow interruption, the implementation may not actually use the explicit sleep function that most OS's provide.

If the current thread is blocked in an invocation of the `wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int)`, `methods of Thread class`, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException.